# What is the possible bug based on the error message "invalid block tag: endif"?

Tags: html, markdown, message

Hi sorry that I may not be able to give out more information, but can I ask what the error message (`dir1/dir2/dir3/error.md: Template syntax error: Invalid block tag: 'endif')` may indicate?

So basically I have a HTML and a Markdown file that seem to be linked somehow in an environment, I'm thinking there must be another Django templates existing somewhere that store the variables and values shown in both the HTML and Markdown files. The HTML and markdown files have variables inside like `{%I'mavariable%}`.

I wanted to provide more information, but I don't know much more than this to be honest. But I was told that the corresponding html actually break the build...

So what are some potential possibilities/errors that made the build fail? The `endif` tag may refer to the variable `{% dynamics endif %}` in the html I guess?

Thank you so much!

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].* You don't have to include the exact content of your file, just enough code to reproduce the error. The content can be replaced with lorem ipsum if necessary.

Comment: also: what program gives you that error message when you do what exactly?

Comment: Based on your posting history I'm going to assume this is actually an issue with Django-family templates, where [`{% endif %}` is a built-in tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#if).

Comment: I just edited the question, but to be honest, I don't know much more than what I described. So thanks guys!